# парадокс с правами доступа

Tags: unix

не могу прочитать папку `dnup`. Захожу с владельца, права доступа 666. не думал что в линуксе могут быть такие фантомные проблемы. Ещё вчера спокойно заходил и делал всё что надо. Или я упуская что-то совсем очевидное? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: для просмотра содержимого папки нужен executable bit на этой папке

Comment: «я упуская что-то совсем очевидное» — да :)

Comment: @etki я думал что исполняемый бит нужен только на исполняемые  файлы. С чем это связано?

Comment: @AndreyYurevich с тем, что вы не знали, что исполняемый бит нужен и для просмотра содержимого папки тоже :)

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 0, accepted):

биты, которые в символической нотации отображаются символом `x`, [называются `execute/search`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/chmod.html). слово `execute` относится к файлам, а слово `search` — к каталогам.

наличием/отсутствием данных битов (у каталога) разрешается/запрещается осуществление поиска в данном каталоге (для соответствующих категорий пользователей — владельца, группы и остальных).